# Setting form validation rules in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have these issue where I want to set a rules on three input forms of type "text", my rule is that **at least** one of these three has values (**either of the three**), I have no idea how to set them in CI, because they are altogether executed when run() is triggered, any on of you guys knows how to set these kind of rules to form validation in CI please do share your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your own type of validation functions. It is pretty well documented [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), but an excerpt would be:

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function username_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

`callback_username_check` is calling the `username_check` function in the controller

**To answer your latest comment**

```
// $data is $_POST 
function my_form_validator($data)
{
    $data = 'dont worry about this';
    // you have access to $_POST here
    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];


    if($field1 OR $field2 OR $field3)
    {
        // your fields have value       
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // your fields dont have any value
        $this->form_validation->set_message('field1', 'At least one of the 3 fields should have a value');

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see how do it allow 3 inputs even though only 1 of the 3 has a value

Comment: ohh so thats how it goes, imma try this one

Comment: if thats the case, it can be passed an extra data, so where doest field2 and 3 came from? field1 is the only form name passed at the 1st params of setmessage

Comment: hmm you have a point there though.. but how then can you validate that concatenated word?, all i know is passing the input name from the input html tag usiing CI's form validation ofcourse

Comment: I just tested, in your `my_form_validator()` class, you have access to the `$_POST` array. Should be no problem accessing all of your form field values.

Comment: hmmm yeah but about your hack and about your edited answer.. the one being passed by the $data variable, i assume its an array, how do i pass it on the set_rules method?

Comment: no need to pass $_POST as an argument anymore. just use `callback_username_check` on its own in the validation check, all should be good. Please delete our comments afterwards as its a mess :)

Comment: one last thing, about the hack, how do you validate $form in $form = $field1.$field2.$field3; i mean how do you do set_rules() on php variable?

Comment: no need to do that any more. just do as I said in the original answer. I will modify it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26806/discussion-between-lemoncodes-and-mehrdad-dastgir)

Comment: please enter chat your code doesn't seem to work when i implemented it